# Are there any Android apps similar to RunKeeper, but for things other than running or cardio workouts?

Tags: exercise, workout, training, app

RunKeeper is great for tracking running outside, with the GPS and coaching. More recently, I've started using the ability to track workouts on ellipticals and treadmills.

However, I haven't found a suitable app to track other workouts - number of pushups or situps, or weight and reps on weight machines. I just want to track the date of the workout, the type of exercise done or machine used, the weight lifted (if appropriate - it wouldn't be for tracking pushups, situps, etc.), and the number of sets and reps performed. I then want to have access to historical data and trends so I can track performance.

Is there an app like this? I would prefer something that uses a cloud service for storing data, as opposed to storing in a local database. The service should also show trends and historical data about workouts. Sharing of data is optional, but would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a heart rate monitor? Because without gps, there's not much to track when you're not moving yourself. Else you're stuck with manually filling in the time + kcal calculated by the machine (if available)

Comment: @Ivo No, but I don't see how that matters for things that aren't cardio. That's what I'm already doing for RunKeeper - after a treadmill/elliptical run, I enter the time, distance, and other data provided by the machine. Now, I'm looking to have an app where I enter wight + sets/reps + exercise type to track progress, such as lifting more weight, or tracking variations in sets/reps performed.

Comment: Your heart is your body's motor regardless of the type of exercise, so you'll be able to quantify your work outs more easily, but I guess simply tracking them in text format could suffice as well. Either way I suggest you make that emphasize that part a bit more, so others don't make interpret it the wrong way like I did

Comment: @Ivo Is the edit better?

Comment: Yup that's better and it seems @Matt already answered it for you :-)

Comment: Ah, totally missed these comments. I see what you're asking now. I accordingly removed one of the apps I listed in my answer, but the other two seem to fit what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions that may fit your needs. I pulled specific ones out of this [fitness app list on meta](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209/creating-a-compendium-of-fitness-and-nutrition-apps) we're trying to put together. The bullet points all come directly from their respective websites and some quick poking around. I can't personally speak about any experiences I've had with these apps, and that is really subject to what you really like.

---

[**JEFIT**](http://www.jefit.com/)

- Online and iPhone and Android apps
- Meant more for [bodybuilding routines](http://www.jefit.com/exercises/)
- Tracks some [cardio exercises](http://www.jefit.com/exercises/bodypart.php?id=10&exercises=Cardio)

---

[**DailyBurn Tracker**](https://tracker.dailyburn.com/v)

- Cardio tracking
- Weight training tracking
- Android app

---

[Fitocracy](http://www.fitocracy.com/) might be worth looking into, but I can't get in because I don't have an invite code for it. If you want to track weightlifting routines in addition to cardiovascular exercises, JEFIT or DailyBurn will probably suit your needs.

Comment: I'll poke around these when I get home. I've heard of Fitocracy as well, but can't find an invite code.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally found [Gymprovise](http://gymprovise.net) to be an excellent app for planning and tracking my weight training workouts at the gym.

Comment: Can you explain why you like this app and what it does?

Comment: I like it because it has a lot of features, is very customizable and flexible, is easy to use. Most importantly, it is very fluid and non-obtrusive during my workout and really helps me get the most out of it, without crossing the all-important line of interfering with it or demanding my attention excessively - which is a rarity in workout apps IMO. In a sentence, it allows you to create any workout routine, track/record that routine in real time, and view your training progress. It also lets you track progress in weight and body measurements.