# Fitness app advice?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, stronglifts, barbell, app, kettlebell

StackExchange,

I'm new here and have spent the past hour searching the site for potential answers to my question, to no avail. I did find this list of fitness apps: [Creating a compendium of fitness and nutrition apps?](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209/creating-a-compendium-of-fitness-and-nutrition-apps)

However, it doesn't quite get at what I'm asking, so I'll try to explain the situation.

I'm a fit individual, who works out 5-6 times a week with kettlebells, barbell weightlifting and bodyweight exercises.

What I find difficult is putting together my programming instead of just showing up and working out. For example, this morning I decided I would do kettlebell exercises, but I threw together a workout on the fly. In contrast, Monday, Thursdays and Saturdays I do Stronglifts with my girlfriend, which leaves my no wiggle room for throwing something together on the fly, but achieves definable results.

**I'm looking for an app that can put together the disparate pieces of my workout puzzle and prescribe me a program that will help to achieve my goals.**

After looking at most of the apps that exist, it seems that there are a) encyclopedic apps with a ton of exercises but terrible UX, or b) really gimmicky 7-minute booty burner workouts that I wouldn't touch with a ten foot pole.

Does anyone here have recommendations for something similar to what I'm talking about? If you use fitness apps, and even have a bad experience, let me know -- it might be helpful in getting closer to what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: First off, what type of device to you have to use? There is a wonderful iOS app that I have used. If you have an iphone/iPad it may help you with what you seek

Comment: related: [What is the best iOS App for tracking Starting Strength progress](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11654/what-is-the-best-ios-app-for-tracking-starting-strength-progress?rq=1)

Comment: related: [Are there any Android apps similar to RunKeeper, but for things other than running or cardio workouts](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-there-any-android-apps-similar-to-runkeeper-but-for-things-other-than-runni)

Comment: Arober11 those don't necessarily relate to the question. He wants a workout planning app, not a tracking app.

Comment: @PaulWitry: One seems particularly pertinent as the author asked for: **"I need an app that tells me which lifts I am supposed to do on which day."**

Comment: @Arober11 but a running and cardio workout app would not be pertinent. He is specifically looking for something for lifting.

Comment: @PaulWitry: You been over doing it ;) as the other link is asking for an App like Runtastic: **"but for things other than running or cardio "**

Comment: @arober11 my apologies then! :)

Comment: Thank you both. I have Android, I do use a starting strength app for that particular program but, as Paul says, I want a workout planning app. Best would be an app that builds a program

Comment: @arober11 still haven't found what I'm looking for. Found apps such as JeFit, but I find it gimmicky, bad UX, etc. Do you have other options? Do either of you use some sort of fitness app, and would you be willing to tell me what you like/dislike about it? This is turning into a frustrating search!

Comment: For @PaulWitry as well!

Comment: Awesome I'm an android user and an apple user. I've used this app called imuscle 2 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.the3d4medical.imuscle2.smartphones. while it does cost 1.99, it allows you to select the exercises you want for a particular workout routine and compile them into one workout. You van create 5 workouts for every day of the week if you wish,  dedicated to specific muscles (chest, leg day etc) it also has tracking and 3D tutorials. You can search exercise based on which muscle you want to work as well

Comment: I've played with a few, but I'm not really a fan of phones and gyms, and a lot of the apps are gimmicky, they're also not a lot of use on a track. Anyway there are a few comparative reviews around, but nothing jumps out as a must have eg. [Best Android apps for strength training and weight lifting](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-weightlifting-strength-training-apps-93949/). I'm sure your gym will happily sell you a custom workout plan, and you don't even have to ask that nicely ;)

Comment: I should add that you aren't limited to 5 workouts haha

Comment: From a UX perspective, the [SparkPeople](http://www.sparkpeople.com/resource/fitness_plan_generator.asp) site appears fairley clean, just a shame they don't offer the functionality in their App.

Comment: This is probably a bit more labor-intensive than what you want, but for me, Google's version of Excel (Google Sheets) has been extremely helpful in creating a program I can follow. I can keep track of all my stats, like weight, reps, body weight, exercise type, and even create graphs detailing my progress over time. The downside is that the process is not automated and I have to write my workout in a notebook before I go to the gym, and later transfer the data to Google Sheets, but it does allow me to customize my program in a way I was not able to before.

Comment: Haven't tried this myself, but a group of my friends used freeletics to generate their workout plan. As far as I understood, it generates you a plan based on your current strength and physics. Worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I use FitNotes in order to keep all of my exercises in one place. You can write down the exercises and divide them to different muscle groups in order to understand on which days you worked on which muscles.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's not looking for a note taking/tracking app, he is looking for an app that says "On this day do this", and makes the program for him.

Comment: What JohnP said :)

Answer (score -1):

I use MyFitnessPal to track nutrition, & Runkeeper to track my runs. Both can by synced together as well! For weight training I use [Evernote](http://www.endofthreefitness.com/how-to-use-evernote-to-dominate-your-fitness/) its pretty BA, you can asctually log workouts on pen and paper and just snap a photo of it on the app!