# Looking for a mobile app that can help me coordinate my workout with my personal trainer

Tags: exercise, tracking, app, personal-training

**Not looking for opinion on which one is the "best app out there"**

I have started working out with a personal trainer and have not been able to find an app where:

1. The Personal Trainer can design my workout
2. I/We can track against how I did
3. He The Personal Trainer can possibly design sessions when I don't train with him

I am aware of the following apps but they don't suite my bill:

1. Lifting Log
2. Fit77
3. LiftBig
4. HIIT

Thanks.

Comment: On the metasite, there is a list of app/websites, see http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/209/creating-a-compendium-of-fitness-and-nutrition-apps/210#210. Regarding what you are looking for, maybe the swedish/US start up Vint can help you https://www.joinvint.com/

Comment: @FredrikD, I downloaded vint but it seems to be more of a groupon for fitness.

Comment: related: [Fitness app advice](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25476/fitness-app-advice)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about software recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been training for quite some time and the best app I have found so far has been the app of Bodybuilding.com . There is an entire web space devoted to people that train and like the training and nutrition part. You can download the app on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bodybuilding.mobile&hl=en) if you are an Android user and on the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bodyspace-social-fitness-app/id687818146?mt=8) if you are an iOS user. Here is the link to Android:

What will probably suit you is that there is the opportunity to create your personal plan as well as choose somebody else's plan to follow. If your trainer has created a workout, you can simply say that you will do it and select the given workout you are looking for. 
The app has a timer that you can start once you have clicked on an exercise, you can friend people with similar interests etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question here: "[Personal Trainers: Do you like the idea of an app for PTs to set schedules for their clients, online or offline and they can also see the clients progress (weight, BMI, fats etc) and give them follow up call when required?](https://www.quora.com/Personal-Trainers/Do-you-like-the-idea-of-an-app-for-PTs-to-set-schedules-for-their-clients-online-or-offline-and-they-can-also-see-the-clients-progress-weight-BMI-fats-etc-and-give-them-follow-up-call-when-required)", that suggests [Fitness Hawk](http://www.fitnesshawkapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out www.dojofitness.io

I believe this app covers all your needs. It allows you to work with your trainer via the app to design workout & diet plans and track / monitor progress. It also allows you to post results and compete with friends.

Comment: Hi Nate, do you work for dojofitness, I wasn't able to find anything substantiative at the site -- plus the site looks like it's very early stage.